# How to use appscript to activate if formula value changes from false to true it will populate beside the cell true

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, google-sheets

For googlesheet.

I have an appscript that runs base on change that populate the row from E to H with formula and copy paste as value (except column H* it has formula that checks sheet 3 if the input digit matches with column C) if column A to D gets updated via whatsapp API user input. A security pin will be sent to their email (Security pin will never repeat). When the user send to whatsapp the 5/6 digit pin it will be added into googlesheet sheet3 column B it will then trigger the appscript formula and then it will be pasted as value.

i want to ask when Column H formula changes from false to true after matching the column C how can i run an appscript ON change and it will write true beside the cell that changed from false to true.

This is my attempt but it did not work

```
function falsetotrueupdate(e) {
   var sheet = e.source.getActiveSheet();
   var editedCell = e.source.getActiveRange();

   // check if edited cell is in column I and the formula in the edited cell evaluates to TRUE
       if (editedCell.getColumn() == 9 && editedCell.getFormula() ==    '=IFERROR(IF(MATCH($H1,Sheet3!$C:$C,0)>0,"True","False"),"False")' && editedCell.getValue() == true) {

    // get the row of the edited cell
        var row = editedCell.getRow();
        var targetSheet = "Sheet3";
        var targetRange = sheet.getRange("J" + row);

    // set the value of column J to "True"
        targetRange.setValue("True");
  }
}
```

Comment: AFAIK there are no triggers that fire on formula changes

Comment: if i understand what you are wanting correctly, i believe the only way to accomplish something like that would be to have a time based trigger that runs every few minutes and checks the values and sets the values. this is not an optimal solution.